# How to delete everything after a dash and put the remaining text on 4 characters in DAX?

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, dax

I have in Visual Studio a table `Y2_Sales` which contains a column "`color`" with values like this :

```
85-GREY MARLE
90-BLACK
90-BLACK
1000-WHITE
49-NAVY
90-BLACK
3021-BONE
```

I would like to make a calculated column in my template and delete everything after the dash and put the remaining numbers on 4 characters, which would give :

```
0085
0090
0090
1000
0049
0090
3021
```

I tried this formula but it returns me for example `90-` how to remove this last dash?

```
=LEFT([color],
IF (SEARCH("-",[color],1,0) > 0, 
    SEARCH("-",[color],1,0), 
        LEN([color])
         )
     )
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier in the Query Editor. You can define a custom column as

```
Text.PadStart(Text.BeforeDelimiter([color], "-"), 4, "0")
```

but you can do it with DAX too.

```
Padded =
VAR Length = SEARCH ( "-", [color], 1, 0 ) - 1
RETURN
    REPT ( "0", 4 - Length ) & LEFT ( [color], Length )
```

Here, `Length` is the length of the string before the dash and `REPT` repeats `0` to do the left padding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanations, but when I put your formula I get an error that tells me "An argument of function LEFT has the wrong data type or an invalid value"

Comment: To get past this error I had to put this: =VAR Length = SEARCH ( "-", [color], 1, 0 ) - 1
RETURN
    REPT ( "0", 4 - Length ) & IFERROR(LEFT ( [color], Length ),[color])

Comment: Sounds like you have some [color] without -.

Comment: I have some colors that are empty yes in my column, so the error comes from there?

Comment: Yes. You’re tweak looks fine though.

Comment: Can't you think of a better one? Yes, it does show the color on 4 characters as I wanted.